# What's the meaning of the sentence below?

Tags: sentence-meaning

If the world takes the shape of whatever the most powerful AI is programmed (or reprograms itself) to desire, it even opens the possibility of evolution taking a turn for the entirely banal – could an AI destroy humankind from a desire to produce the most paperclips for example?

Comment: As it stands it's somewhat unclear to me the exact question you have as well as a bit broad. Could you please, be more explicit on the exact point of your question?

Comment: Uh… it's a question, not something that needs *meaning*. Did you mean, rather, "What's the answer to the question/sentence below?"

Either way, can you explain how any Answer would not be opinion, or literary criticism?

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is a question that is ultimately rhetorical and self-answering.  It's pondering the possibility that a super-powerful AI (artificial intelligence) could reshape the world and destroy humanity in it's quest to achieve some objective- even a banal (stupid, bland) objective like making paperclips.